# Encrypting a file name in linux?

Tags: linux, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt a file as well as its filename.
Encrypting the file is fairly easy, I use gpg for that, but I can't figure out how to encrypt the filename as well.
Would be great if the filename could be encrypted using the same key.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: `gpg` isn't an option for this as even short messages (e.g. filenames) will end up in quite long encrypted text that will be longer then 255 bytes (max filename length) for any useful key length.

Comment: Consider an encrypted directory or even the whole disk.

Comment: How about doing it manually?

Comment: Or put the file in archive w generic name and encrypt that

Answer (score 2):

> ### [ecryptfs.org](http://ecryptfs.org/)

ecryptfs can encrypt both the file contents and the file names. It's the default home directory encryption scheme supported by Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using `gpg`, I would advise you the following process:

1. Create a directory with a meaningless name (eg. use `mktemp -d`).
2. Copy your file(s) into this directory.
3. Encrypt and compress the archive of this directory with `gpg`:

   ```
   gpg-zip -c -o file.gpg dirname
   ```

You may want to write a shell script to automate this easily.